# rocksdb all compaction jobs done notification

Tags: rocksdb, bulk-load, data-compaction

I use rocksdb's bulk loading mechanism to load a bunch of sst files generated by offline spark tasks. In order to avoid a large number of disk IO during the loading and compacting process from affecting online read requests, I want to finish offline loading, and after the db compact is completed, the nodes will be brought online when there is no disk write IO. Is there such a notification, or some other way to help me do this? I have currently tried the following ways:

- implement EventListener::OnCompactionCompleted, it's based on single compaction job not the whole compaction process which probably have multiple compaction jobs
- after DB::IngestExternalFile returns, call DB::CompactRange(CompactRangeOptions(), nullptr, nullptr) do manual compaction. but there are still some compaction jobs running after compactrange returns

Answer (score 1):

There's not a great interface for this at the moment. Probably the best you can do is periodically poll `DB::GetIntProperty()` on `Properties::kCompactionPending` and `Properties::kNumRunningCompactions` until both are zero.

It might suffice to poll these only on `OnCompactionCompleted` but I wouldn't completely trust that to work reliably for all future versions.

Regarding manual full `DB::CompactRange()`: with no ongoing writes, there should not be any compaction left to do after a full compaction completes, but if you intend to trigger a full compaction, unnecessary automatic compactions might trigger before the manual compaction unless you open with `disable_auto_compactions=true` (each applicable column family). So opening with `disable_auto_compactions=true` and waiting for a full `CompactRange` is another good path to success.